# How to find ma and nb that multiply to c?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to figure out the solution to the following problem: $4585a+6734b=7$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers. I am familiar with how to calculate the $\gcd$, but how can $a$ and $b$ be directly calculated?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. In this website we use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical symbols. We also require that you show your work so we could give better feedback.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm